# Can columns property be used with numbers for several columns?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to teach myself excel VBA and can usually find solutions to problems on the web, particularly this forum. However not in this case.

The requirement is simple - clear the content of several complete columns.

My first code worked

```
Dim home As Range, away As Range
Dim team As Variant
Dim srng As Range 'general range variable
Dim i As Integer, r As Integer
Dim c(1 To 4) As Integer 'Array with 4 variables
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Fixtures")

'Finds last row even if clear contents & blank rows
lastrow = ws.Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Set home = ws.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lastrow, 2)) 'Range imported from web
Set away = ws.Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(lastrow, 4)) 'Range imported from web

'Clear output range
ws.Columns("F:I").ClearContents
'Write header
ws.Cells(1, 6) = "Home Fixtures"
i = 2
With ws
    For Each team In home
        Select Case team.Value
            Case "Charnwood 1", "Charnwood 2", "Charnwood 3", "Charnwood 4"
                r = team.Row
                .Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 4)).Copy .Cells(i, 6)
                i = i + 1
        End Select
    Next
```

Using `ws.Columns("F:I").ClearContents`

I then wanted to use number formats for consistency later changing the row and column within a loop.

```
 'Clear output range
 ws.Columns(6, 9).ClearContents
```

This returned run-time error `'1004'  Application defined or object-defined error`

I ended up using

```
'Clear output range
ws.Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(lastrow, 9)).ClearContents
```

I have tried every numeric format I can think if after `.columns` to no avail.

Is there any way of doing this using .columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
range(columns(1),columns(10)).ClearContents
```